Harfbuzz and Freetype rendering horizontal text within vertical text
I am using Harfbuzz and Freetype to render text. In Korean, when there is some English text in some vertical text, it should be rendered horizontally then rotated 90 degrees. Like this:
Proper Rendering
So, to try to accomplish this I have shaped two pieces of text with Harfbuzz. One vertical, and one horizontal. Then, I have rotated the horizontal text by 90 degrees. This is what I get:
What I get
You can see the problem is that the horizontal text isn't in line with the vertical text. This is because the vertical text has a negative x_offset so that the characters all line up perfectly. If I ignore the x_offset this is what I get:
Ignoring x offset
So now the two line segments are properly aligned, but of course now the vertical text is incorrect because I've ignored the x_offset.
If I could reverse the direction of the x_offset then the result would be what I want. Unfortunately I don't know if there's a property of the freetype font or something in harfbuzz that corresponds to the width I would need to do the x_offset in the opposite direction.
I'm probably just missing something simple, but does anyone know how I can do this?

I believe the correct thing to do is to subtract to descender size of the font from the horizontal text. Especially since we're rendering the text vertically, it doesn't make sense to have a descender.
